# Want an advanced sort filter that search for particular combination of letters in specific column irrespective of its post and pre letters

Tags: excel, vba, filter, module

Here is my data set
[image]

Now I want all all rows having combination of red filter to my sheet2 irrespective of its pre and post letters. I want result like this.

[image]

But could only be able to acheive this using the code below.
[image]

```
Sub FilterCopyToOtherSheet()
'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C14").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E2"), _
        CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), _
        Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this little piece of code, basically what you are looking for is `Criteria1:="*red*"`

```
Sub filter
  With Sheets(1)
    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A2:C" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & .Range("E1") & "*"
    .Range("A2:C" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & .Range("E2") & "*"
    .Range("A2:C" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*" & .Range("E3") & "*"
    .Range("A1:C" & LastRow).Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")
    .ShowAllData
  End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

what you can do is use cells E1, E2, E3 as filter values for your columns 1,2,3 respectively. so if you want to filter "kiwi" in column 1, "red" in column 2 and "Yes" in column 3, put those values in E1-E3 and it will filter these 3 conditions. You can easily change destination, where you want paste your data.

Comment: that works but on the same sheet it filter it out i want the option of "color = red"  in sheet1 and not in code like  Criteria1:="*red*" and one more thing that the filtered data goes to sheet 2.

Comment: i want to shift criteria cells to sheet3 what to do now ? i made it like this Sheet3.Range("E1") it is working want to ask if it is right or not

Comment: it should be Sheets(3) - 3rd sheet in workbook or Sheets("Name") for refering to sheet name

Comment: can you make it work for number combination as wll like 220 or 132 etc

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a helper-column with the code =search($E$2,B2) in Cell D2, pull the formula down and filter for it's result? (Of course you can tinker with the formula to make it more pretty first.)